# CamelCase Search with Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, full-text-search, analyzer, camelcasing

I want to configure Elasticsearch, so that searching for "JaFNam" will create a good score for "JavaFileName".

I'm tried to build an analyzer, that combines a CamelCase `pattern` analyzer with an `edge_ngram` tokenizer. I thought this would create terms like these:

```
J F N Ja Fi Na Jav Fil Nam Java File Name
```

But the tokenizer seems not to have any effect: I keep getting these terms:

```
Java File Name
```

What would the correct Elasticsearch configuration look like?

---

Example code:

```
curl -XPUT    'http://127.0.0.1:9010/hello?pretty=1' -d'
{
  "settings":{
    "analysis":{
      "analyzer":{
        "camel":{
          "type":"pattern",
          "pattern":"([^\\p{L}\\d]+)|(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)|(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)|(?<=[\\p{L}&&[^\\p{Lu}]])(?=\\p{Lu})|(?<=\\p{Lu})(?=\\p{Lu}[\\p{L}&&[^\\p{Lu}]])",
          "filters": ["edge_ngram"]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
'
curl -XGET    'http://127.0.0.1:9010/hello/_analyze?pretty=1' -d'
{
  "analyzer":"camel",
  "text":"JavaFileName"
}'
```

results in:

```
{
  "tokens" : [ {
    "token" : "java",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 4,
    "type" : "word",
    "position" : 0
  }, {
    "token" : "file",
    "start_offset" : 4,
    "end_offset" : 8,
    "type" : "word",
    "position" : 1
  }, {
    "token" : "name",
    "start_offset" : 8,
    "end_offset" : 12,
    "type" : "word",
    "position" : 2
  } ]
}
```

Comment: You can only have a single tokenizer, either `pattern` or `edge_ngram` but not both at the same time. Besides, I'm not sure why the character case should make any difference. How different is it from searching `JaFNam` or `jafnam`?

Comment: @Val eclipse and IntelliJ IDEs use that kind of "case interpretation". They interpret `JaFNam` and `jafnam` differently. I want to use the same behavior for my search.

Comment: @Val Can I use a `edge_ngram` *filter* instead of an `edge_ngram` tokenizer to achieve the desired behaviour?

Comment: yes there's also an `edge_ngram` filter, you can try

Comment: @Val Sadly I get the same results when using a filter. I updated my question to use filter instead of tokenizer.

Comment: You analyzer definition is not correct. you need a `tokenizer` and an array of  `filter`, as it is your analyzer doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You analyzer definition is not correct. you need a `tokenizer` and an array of  `filter`, as it is your analyzer doesn't work. Try like this instead:

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "camel": {
          "tokenizer": "my_pattern",
          "filter": [
            "my_gram"
          ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "my_gram": {
          "type": "edge_ngram",
          "max_gram": 10
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "my_pattern": {
          "type": "pattern",
          "pattern": "([^\\p{L}\\d]+)|(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)|(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)|(?<=[\\p{L}&&[^\\p{Lu}]])(?=\\p{Lu})|(?<=\\p{Lu})(?=\\p{Lu}[\\p{L}&&[^\\p{Lu}]])"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh yes, `max_gram` is 2 by default. I've updated my answer